# Designing a Singleton to house application settings?

Tags: c#, oop, singleton, class-design

I'm designing an application that synchronizes data between two third party services. In one of the services, there are a variety of Ids that I fetch on application startup (or pool refresh) and slap into a struct with static properties.

For example

```
public struct SfRecordTypes
{
    public static string Order = "REMOVED";
    public static string Issue = "REMOVED";
}

public struct SfQueues
{
    public static string Billing = "REMOVED";
    public static string Support = "REMOVED";
    public static string SupportDev = "REMOVED";
    public static string Field = "REMOVED";
}
```

And on start-up these are called.

```
public static void PopulateRecordTypes()
{
    var sf = new SalesForce();
    var recordTypes = sf.GetRecordTypes();
    if (recordTypes == null) return;
    SfRecordTypes.Order = recordTypes.First(n => n.Name != null && n.Name.Contains("Order")).Id;
    SfRecordTypes.Issue = recordTypes.First(n => n.Name != null && n.Name.Contains("Issue")).Id;

    sf.Dispose();
}

public static void PopulateQueueIDs()
{
    var sf = new SalesForce();
    var groups = sf.GetAllGroups();
    if (groups == null) return;
    SfQueues.Billing = groups.First(n => n.Name != null && n.Name.Contains("Billing Queue")).Id;
    SfQueues.Support = groups.First(n => n.Name != null && n.Name.Contains("Support Queue")).Id;
    SfQueues.SupportDev = groups.First(n => n.Name != null && n.Name.Contains("Support Developer Queue")).Id;
    SfQueues.Field = groups.First(n => n.Name != null && n.Name.Contains("Field Services Queue")).Id;

    sf.Dispose();
}
```

However, I'm trying to figure out how to design/implement a singleton class that I can call that will automatically populate these values (in a manner that makes them read-only), so that when I use them in the future, they follow proper OOP principles and are a bit cleaner. I'm a bit new to singletons and my research has popped up mixed results.

Comment: Well going from static fields to a singleton is a *start* - but why make it a singleton at all? Why do you want to treat this as global state? Hint: you've got a method which returns `void`... why not return an object populated with the results instead?

Comment: These calls can be a bit expensive to make, often taking several seconds. I essentially want them to be initialized on their first use, and persist until a recycle happens. They're marked void right now as they populate the fields on application startup in `global.asax`. By using a singleton, I can move away from these static classes a bit.

Comment: Or you could use dependency injection, initialize the values on start-up, but make sure the same object happens to be supplied everywhere it's needed. Then you can still test easily with different values. I would really *try* to avoid singletons...

Comment: I'm already using a few singletons (granted they're cookie cutter) that hold onto massive lists of users, organizations, etc that are custom cache objects. Why would avoiding singletons be beneficial?

Comment: Global state is hard to reason about, and hard to test. I suggest you research this a bit - searching for "why are singletons evil" gives a lot of hits :)

Comment: I started heading this direction due to our developers suggesting it. I just can't think of another design pattern that solves what I'm after. For example, if I need a persistent list of `user` objects that is globally accessible for all incoming connections, and I do not watch them refetched from the web service, it seemed like the only viable option.

Comment: Then you should look into dependency injection. Most dependency injection frameworks let you make a binding "in a singleton scope" so that a single instance is used... but without it being an actual singleton in the normal sense, which allows simpler testing etc.